# Undefined Index error (from Database)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Name      | MyPrice | MyStock |
------------------------------
blue_pill |   20    | Yes     |
------------------------------
red_pill  |   10    | No      |
------------------------------
```

I want a code that will easily allow me to define 4 variables (2 of the price of each item, 2 with the stock status of each item).

(In general, I will have much more than 2 items, so I'm looking for the best practice to get those variables.)

So I have the following code, but it doesn't work, I get error:

`Notice: Undefined index: name` 
(shows 6 times)

`Notice: Undefined index: stock` 
(shows 2 times)

```
$item1 = "blue_pill";
$item2 = "red_pill";

$productList = array();
$products = $mysqli->query("select * from table_products where Name IN ('$item1', '$item2')");
if($products){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)){
        $productList[$product['name']]['MyPrice'] = $product['name']; //Errors Start Here
        $productList[$product['name']]['MyStock'] = $product['stock'];
    }
}

//first product: 

$price1 = $productList[$item1]['price']; 
$red_pill_stock = $productList[$item1]['stock'];

//second product: 

$price2 = $productList[$item2]['price'];
$blue_pill_stock = $productList[$item2]['stock'];
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: They're `Name` and `MyStock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns' names are really `Name` and `MyStock` then your values are in `$product` item with **exactly** such indexes - `Name` and `MyStock`:

```
if($products){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)){
        $productList[$product['name']]['MyPrice'] = $product['Name']; // Index here
        $productList[$product['name']]['MyStock'] = $product['MyStock']; // Index here
    }
}
```

Or if you're not sure what keys are there, `print_r($product)` and check.

Comment: is there a way to make it work without having to be case-sensitive?

Comment: Simple answer is **no**, array keys are case sensitive, i.e `name` and `Name` and `NAME` are different keys. But you can write some function which will check something like `if key exists else if Key exists...`.